# Black background not appearing in Mixed reality capture (MRTK)

Tags: video-capture, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

Having created an application in Unity for the Hololens 1 and setting the skybox to be visible in the Skybox settings, I am able to now see the sky (including the night sky - a black background with white dots representing stars) when using the application. However, when recording a mixed reality video (as per the instructions here at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/holographic-photos-and-videos#capture-a-mixed-reality-video) the night sky is not captured in the video and you can only see objects in the night sky on black surfaces (while the video is recording, the application still renders the night sky normally). You can see the result of a video capture here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OCIytZaQKE&t=30s from 1:59-2:03 on the black TV screen.

Why is the night sky being rendered in the application, but not in the video? Moreover, is there a way to record the video with the black background/night sky in it?

Answer (score 2):

You cleared backbuffer with transparent black which is invisible on video. You need to render the black sky with non-transparent black then.